# Can you help me write this $n^n$ related sequence so that the sum over divisors notation is used?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I need help writing the following sequence:

$$a(n)=0,\frac{\log (2)}{2},\frac{1}{3} \log \left(\frac{9}{2}\right),\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\frac{32}{3}\right),\frac{1}{5} \log \left(\frac{625}{24}\right),\frac{1}{6} \log \left(\frac{324}{5}\right),\frac{1}{7} \log \left(\frac{117649}{720}\right),\frac{1}{8} \log \left(\frac{131072}{315}\right),\frac{1}{9} \log \left(\frac{4782969}{4480}\right),\frac{1}{10} \log \left(\frac{1562500}{567}\right),\frac{1}{11} \log \left(\frac{25937424601}{3628800}\right),\frac{1}{12} \log \left(\frac{35831808}{1925}\right),\frac{1}{13} \log \left(\frac{23298085122481}{479001600}\right),\frac{1}{14} \log \left(\frac{110730297608}{868725}\right),\frac{1}{15} \log \left(\frac{4805419921875}{14350336}\right),\frac{1}{16} \log \left(\frac{562949953421312}{638512875}\right),\frac{1}{17} \log \left(\frac{48661191875666868481}{20922789888000}\right),\frac{1}{18} \log \left(\frac{91507169819844}{14889875}\right),\frac{1}{19} \log \left(\frac{104127350297911241532841}{6402373705728000}\right)...$$

in terms of $$n^n$$

The form is known to be:

$$\sum_{k|n}\;? = n^n$$

or more loosely:

$$\sum_{k|n}\;g(a(n)) = f(n^n)$$

where sum on left is over positive divisors,$k$, of $n$.

> What should I write in the question mark using sequence $a(n)$ so that the sum over the divisors becomes $n^n$?

Program I used in Mathematica is:

```
(*Mathematica start*)
Clear[n, k, s, t, nn];
s = 1;
nn = 19;
A = Table[Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
B = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[k, n] == 0, MoebiusMu[n]*n, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, 
    nn}];
(*Matrix A191898:*)
MatrixForm[T = A.B];
a = FullSimplify[
  Table[Sum[
    If[Mod[n1, n] == 0, 
     Sum[T[[n, k]]/n Log[(n^s/k^s)]/n1^(s - 1), {k, 1, n}], 0], {n, 1,
      n1}], {n1, 1, nn}]]
(*The Riemann zeta function*)
r = FullSimplify[
   Table[Sum[
     If[Mod[n1, n] == 0, 
      Sum[T[[n, k]]/n (n^s/k^s)/n1^(s - 1), {k, 1, n}], 0], {n, 1, 
      n1}], {n1, 1, nn}]];
HarmonicNumber[Range[nn], s];
(*Recurrence*)
Clear[t];
t[1, 1] = 0; 
t[n_, k_] := 
 t[n, k] = 
  If[k == 1, a[[n]] - Sum[t[n, k + i], {i, 1, n - 1}], 
   If[Mod[n, k] == 0, t[n/k, 1], 0], 0];
b = FullSimplify[Table[Exp[t[n, 1]*n]*n!, {n, 1, nn}]]
```

Comment: What is the definition of $a(n)$? Also, this might be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula

Comment: I will add a definition of $a(n)$.

Comment: Actually this is my problem, I don't know how to define the sequence. I only know how to write it in a very complicated way as in the program.

Comment: Are you saying that $\sum_{k=1}^n a(n)=n^n$?

Comment: No not exactly, but almost. You need to apply (to $a(n)$) the exponential function, factorials and mulitply with natural numbers to make the left hand side equal the right hand side.

Comment: Actually now when I look at it, I have written the relation wrong.

Comment: It would be better not to reduce the fractions.  It looks like the general term is $a(n)=\frac 1n \log \left(\frac {n^{n-1}}{n!}\right)$  It would be even better to provide the formula for the general term.  Using Stirling's approximation this becomes $a(n) \approx \frac 1n (n-\frac 12(\log n -\log (2\pi))\approx 1$  Why do you expect a formula for $n^n$ to come out of that?  It grows quickly and does not depend on the number of divisors of $n$

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I now realized I asked the question about the wrong sequence. And Ross Millikan is correct.